cudf is very slow
I have a code with heavy use of dataframes and lots of computation. I want to speed up the process time so I bought a Nvidia GPU and try to implement it using the cudf library. But performance is awful. benchmark code below run very slow on gpu. reading the comments, I changed the data types to int32 but result is the same.
import cudf as cd
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time
import cupy as cp

# Generating random data
np.random.seed(42)
size = 1000
iteration = 1000

data = {
    'type': np.random.choice(['X', 'Y'], size=size ),
    'num1': np.random.randint(10, 1001, size=size, dtype='int32'),
    'num2': np.random.randint(1000, 100001, size=size, dtype='int32')
}

print(f"cudf version:{cd.__version__}")


# Creating DataFrame
df_cpu = pd.DataFrame(data)
df_gpu = cd.DataFrame(data)

df_cpu['num2'] = df_cpu['num2'].astype(np.float32)
df_gpu['num2'] = df_gpu['num2'].astype(np.float32)

for i in range (2):

    t = time.time()
    for i in range(iteration):
        temp = sum(df_cpu[df_cpu.type == 'X']['num1'].values)
    print(f'filtering in cpu in {time.time()- t}')

    t = time.time()
    for i in range(iteration):
        temp = sum(df_cpu.loc[df_cpu.type == 'X', 'num1'].values)
    print(f'filtering with loc cpu in {time.time()- t}')

    t = time.time()
    for i in range(iteration):
        temp = sum(df_gpu[df_gpu.type == 'X']['num1'].values)
    print(f'filtering in gpu in {time.time()- t}')

    t = time.time()
    for i in range(iteration):
        temp = sum(df_gpu.loc[df_gpu.type == 'X', 'num1'].values)
    print(f'filtering with loc in gpu in {time.time()- t}')

cudf version:24.06.00
filtering in cpu in 0.14927053451538086
filtering with loc cpu in 0.13542795181274414
filtering in gpu in 7.799736738204956
filtering with loc in gpu in 7.769643783569336
filtering in cpu in 0.1468029022216797
filtering with loc cpu in 0.13495588302612305
filtering in gpu in 7.765619993209839
filtering with loc in gpu in 7.761591672897339

What am I missing? I need to fully utilize gpu and increase performance

Your GPU is a RTX 4070 Ti/Super designed to compute 32-bit numbers efficiently, not 64-bit ones. Your GPU is VERY slow for 64-bit number. It can reach 40-44 TFlops in SP but only 0.5-0.6 TFlops in DP. A CPU at the same price can clearly archive the same performance in DP, if not even better. You may get a speed up thanks to the high-throughput memory bandwidth though (typically 6-7x faster than 1 high-end CPUs). In your code, you use 64-bit numbers. Try with 32-bit one if you can.

Moreover, the computation is done in CPU caches (L1) because the dataframe is small so you do not benefit much from the RAM speed difference and the computation should even be rather compute-bound (especially on CPUs which are very good for this specific use-case).

Last but not least, GPU are massively parallel so they are designed for rather large datasets. Here the amount of parallelism is 1000 while your GPU has 8000 CUDA cores so this is clearly not enough. You need at least 10 times more parallelism for your GPU to be efficient (ideally >50x). Try to increase the dataframe size to 100_000 rows.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

@Jeromo, At first I tried with 100K-1M rows but it did not finish. Then I decreased no of rows for test purposes. In my code, I have a dataframe which has transactions. I need to get sum, mean, min, max within dataframe. summation result can reach several billions. How can I set 32-64 bit? Can I use cudf for numbers that are this big?

cuDF performs best when the data sizes are large enough to fill the GPU hardware. As a very rough estimate, you want to have 100,000 rows or more to get good GPU performance. Often, it is not possible to beat CPU performance on very small dataframes due to the overhead of copying data to/from the GPU.
One key issue is that the sum call in sum(df_gpu[df_gpu.type == 'X']['num1'].values) is happening on the CPU. You should use the cuDF API Series.sum() to accelerate this on the GPU. (https://docs.rapids.ai/api/cudf/stable/user_guide/api_docs/api/cudf.series.sum/)
Here is a slightly modified script and benchmark. I made the benchmark use 1,000,000 rows, 10 iterations, and changed to call Series.sum():
import cudf as cd
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time
import cupy as cp

# Generating random data
np.random.seed(42)
size = 1000000
iteration = 10

data = {
    'type': np.random.choice(['X', 'Y'], size=size ),
    'num1': np.random.randint(10, 1001, size=size, dtype='int32'),
    'num2': np.random.randint(1000, 100001, size=size, dtype='int32')
}

print(f"cudf version:{cd.__version__}")


# Creating DataFrame
df_cpu = pd.DataFrame(data)
df_gpu = cd.DataFrame(data)

df_cpu['num2'] = df_cpu['num2'].astype(np.float32)
df_gpu['num2'] = df_gpu['num2'].astype(np.float32)

for i in range (2):
    t = time.time()
    for i in range(iteration):
        temp = sum(df_cpu[df_cpu.type == 'X']['num1'].values)
    print(f'filtering in cpu in {time.time()- t}')

    t = time.time()
    for i in range(iteration):
        temp = sum(df_cpu.loc[df_cpu.type == 'X', 'num1'].values)
    print(f'filtering with loc cpu in {time.time()- t}')

    t = time.time()
    for i in range(iteration):
        temp = df_gpu[df_gpu.type == 'X']['num1'].sum()
    print(f'filtering in gpu in {time.time()- t}')

    t = time.time()
    for i in range(iteration):
        temp = df_gpu.loc[df_gpu.type == 'X', 'num1'].sum()
    print(f'filtering with loc in gpu in {time.time()- t}')

With these changes, the script shows between 30x - 60x speedup when using cudf (GPU) compared to pandas (CPU). This benchmark was run on Google Colab with a free GPU runtime on a T4 GPU. Benchmark results:
filtering in cpu in 5.781566381454468
filtering with loc cpu in 3.987734317779541
filtering in gpu in 0.1634678840637207
filtering with loc in gpu in 0.06808733940124512
filtering in cpu in 2.9417083263397217
filtering with loc cpu in 1.4086244106292725
filtering in gpu in 0.047949790954589844
filtering with loc in gpu in 0.03043818473815918


Note some benefit is given by using pandas Series.sum() as opposed to python sum as well, so the above isn't exactly apples-to-apples. On my hardware, replacing the df_cpu calls to use Series.sum() like the GPU calls provides a 40% speedup in and of itself. Still doesn't change the tenor of the overall result (GPU would still be about 25x faster than CPU) but just goes to show never use Python sum on a Cythonized object...
